# jquery .load() with multiple variables from one class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to use a class to send the server a list of values for my search like:
SQL....

```
WHERE BRP.BRPID IN (655,123,124,125)
```

Currently I'm using this jquery load:

```
$(function() {
$("#FS").load("Ajax/FS.htm",{BRPIDs: $(".BRPIDs").html()}, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success"){}
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error"){
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
    });
});
```

and there are 0 to many of these on the page:

```
<div class="BRPIDs" style="visibility: hidden;">655</div>
```

The code is only providing 1 value, the first one on the page. OF course I don't know how many there will be as the page is dynamic and will have from 0 to many.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is expected result ? Are you trying to send the `html` of all `.BRPIDs` elements as `data` within `document` at `.load()` call

Comment: Yes, I want to send a list of BRPIDs as a Parameter of the .load()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.map()` to iterate all `.BRPIDs` elements in `document` ; return element `HTMLElement.textContent` within `$.map()` callback; `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `","` to set resulting array returned by `$.map()` to a string containing `.textContent` of all `.BRPIDs` elements in `document` separated by comma character `","`

```
var data = $.map($(".BRPIDs"), function(el) {return el.textContent}).join(",");

$("#FS").load("Ajax/FS.htm",{BRPIDs: data}, function(){// do stuff})
```

Comment: Dang! That works like a Champ! Accepting as the answer and up-voting now.